# how to pick the most suitable design pattern

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture, workflow

I have a problem  which  is as follows.

We are starting to  accept corporate cards in our Kiosks, The corporate cards authorization algorithm/routines will be different for companies. We would like to have a design in place which will help us to add a new algorithm/routines to the existing system with minimum coding  whenever a company approaches us with their algorithm/routines.

Thanks in advance,

Joe.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little ?
what type of cards ?
what system do you currently use ?
what are the expectations of the companies ?

Comment: The cards will be magnetic cards like our normal ATM cards. The cards are used to pay for various services offered by us to the employees of a company . Card interface/Card Reader will provide us the card number which will be used by our software to authenticate the card. This is no current system. All companies need to securely authenticate the card with their central server with the protocol they specified.

Comment: basicly i have built the SAME project before (10 yeards ago)
but we were supplying a preProgrammed POS that was connecting by CDMA to our server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Strategy design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx)

Guess this would be the closest to what you are trying to achieve!

You will need a CardStrategyBase class with standard methods to handle the work.
Then, Card1Strategy class, Card2Strategy class,... etc. Will have the actual algorithm implementation specific to each card type. All stuff common to all card types can go into the CardStrategyBase class.

Answer (score 2):

As other folks said, [Strategy Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx) suits this scenario very well.

When your entities (Companies) differ in behavior(Authorization), encapsulate the behavior and make it separate from the entities' definition.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Strategy Pattern http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy this is good reference for your work

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Inversion (DI).

The "problem" with the strategy pattern is that it while it let's you pick from a list of available implementations it doesn't address adding new implementations for new cards.

Generally speaking, most decent DI implementations allow you to drop new implementations in without having to do a major deployment; after which it might only be a matter of adding appropriate configuration to enable the new implementation(s).